# FullCalendar error : Uncaught TypeError: calendar.fullCalendar is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I have been getting an error when I want to add an event on fullcalendar, my code is correct because the console detects the day I click on it.

I looked at the topics that dealt with the same error but none of them allowed me to solve this error.

Except that an error occurs:
[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOh8D.png)

And here is my code :

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
            locale: 'fr',
            editable: true,
            eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
                if (event.allDay === 'true') {
                    event.allDay = true;
                } else {
                    event.allDay = false;
                }
            },
            events: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/calendar',
            displayEventTime: false,
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            select: function(start, end, allDay) {
                var title = prompt('Nom événement :');
                if (title) {
                    var start = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10);
                    var end = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10);
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/calendarAjax',
                        data: {
                            title: title,
                            start: start,
                            end: end,
                            type: 'add',
                        },
                        type: 'POST',
                        success: function(donnees) {
                            calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent', {
                                id: donnees.id,
                                title: title,
                                start: start,
                                end: end,
                                allDay: allDay
                            }, true);
                            calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
                        }
                    });
                }
            },
        });
        calendar.on('dateClick', function(info) {
            console.log('clicked on ' + info.dateStr);
        });
        calendar.render();
    });
</script>
```

Thank you.

Comment: You seem to have been looking at some old documentation or examples, for earlier versions of fullCalendar. If you're stuck, always check the latest documentation: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-addEvent and https://fullcalendar.io/docs/select-callback

Comment: Your eventRender code is also wrong - assuming you're using version 5 then it doesn't exist. But even if it did, the code you wrote within it doesn't do anything useful.